# How to set column when vim starts to scroll right when having a long line ("right margin")?

Tags: margin

I have a long text line in vim.
Vim can display `n` columns before there is no space left to the right, and you have to scroll right to see the rest of the line. When I go column by column to the right with the cursor on that line, as soon as I reach the `n-3` column, vim scrolls to the right. I want to change `n-3` to `n-1`. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you read [`:h 'sidescrolloff'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27sidescrolloff%27)? I think playing with this option and [`:h 'sidescroll'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27sidescroll%27) should help you find the right settings.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Setting sidescrolloff did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As statox suggested, I used `set sidescrolloff=0`. That removes all vertical margins, I like that even better.

Comment: Note that as [`:h 'sidescrolloff'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27sidescrolloff%27) says `0` is the default value for `sidescrolloff` so you probably had it changed somewhere else in you config.

Comment: Note that you can accept your own answer to mark this as resolved.